# Is there any advantage to PreparedStatement#setInt vs inline SQL?

Tags: sql, prepared-statement

I've read [Give me Parameterized SQL or give me death](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) numerous times.

The advantage of Parameterized SQL for Strings, Dates, and floating-point numbers is very obvious and indisputable.

My question is: what about `int`s?

I ask because, oftentimes, if I'm writing a query or update and the only parameter is an `int`, I'll just write an inline sql and append the int as a shortcut (`"select * from table where id = " + id`).

My question: **Are there any advantages to using Parameterized SQL for `int`s alone?**

To illustrate with Java:

Are there any advantage to this:

```
Connection conn;
int id;
String sql = "select * from table where id = ?";
try (PreparedStatement p_stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    p_stmt.setInt(1, id);
    ResultSet results = p_stmt.executeQuery();

    // ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // ...
}
```

over this:

```
Connection conn;
int id;
String sql = "select * from table where id = " + id;
try (Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet results = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    // ...
} catch (SQLException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the biggest advantage would be consistency. If you decide that all SQL built by string concatenation is "wrong", it's easier to verify that your code is "right", compared to a rule like "All SQL built by string concatenation is wrong, except that which deals with ints as parameters".

Another case, say: down the line, you want to introduce sorting or grouping to the query, suddenly, your line turns into something like this:

```
String sql = "select * from table where id = " + id + " order by somecolumn";
```

And hopefully you remembered the space before `order`. And that everyone after you does also.

There is much to be said for doing things only one way, especially when that one way is the right thing most of the time.

Comment: Good answer. And I agree, consistency is important.